# Schwarzschild-like metric in black hole region

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, metric-tensor

We know that in the black hole region $r<2M$ the metric takes the form

$$
g = \Big(1-\frac{2M}{r}\Big)^{-1}\text{d}r^2 - \Big(1-\frac{2M}{r}\Big)\text{d}t^2 + r^2(\text{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \text{d}\phi^2).
$$

How do we prove (mathematically) that along a timelike curve, $r$ decreases with proper time $\tau$? Similarly how do we know that in the Schwarzschild region $r>2M$, along any timelike curve, $t$ increases with proper time?

Comment: "The question is..." makes it sound like this is homework. If so, then please follow our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange This means adding the homework-and-exercises tag, citing the source of the question, making an effort at solution, and having a conceptual aspect to your question. Even if this was not homework, you could tell us what you tried.

Comment: Editing out the words "The question is..." doesn't address the issue of our homework policy.  I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot actually show that $r$ must always decrease, because the metric can describe both a black hole and a white hole: the latter is similar to a black hole, except that everything must move out instead of moving in.

What you can do is show that $r$ must be a monotonic function of $\tau$: either always increasing or always decreasing. This is pretty straightforward: begin by writing the proper time as

$$-d\tau^2 = - \frac{dr^2}{2M/r-1} + \left(\frac{2M}{r}-1\right) dt^2 + r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta\ d\varphi^2),$$

with $2M/r-1 > 0$. Now simply divide through by $d\tau$ and solve for $dr/d\tau \equiv \dot{r}$ to get

$$\frac{\dot{r}^2}{2M/r-1} = 1 + \left(\frac{2M}{r}-1\right) \left[\dot{t}^2 + r^2(\dot{\theta}^2 + \sin^2\theta\, \dot{\varphi}^2)\right].$$

You can see here that $\dot{r}^2$ is manifestly positive: it can never be zero, so $\dot{r}$ can never change sign. In particular, if $dr/d\tau < 0$ at some point with $r < 2M$, it will stay negative.

Comment: Can you use this method to show that $dt / d\tau$ is also monotonic? At first glance rearranging your second equation for $\dot{t}^2$ gives an expression that could be positive or negative.

Comment: @Archimaredes: you are correct; inside a black hole, $t$ can increase or decrease.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Javier's answer...

For simplicity let's consider radial geodesics such that $\dot{\theta}=\dot{\varphi}=0$ and define $f(r)\equiv\frac{2M}{r}-1.$ Construct the Lagrangian $$2\mathcal{L}=g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu\dot{x}^\nu=-\frac{\dot{r}^2}{f(r)}+f(r)\dot{t}^2.$$

The Euler-Lagrange equation for $t$ is

$$\frac{d}{d\tau} \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\dot{t}}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial t},$$

which yields $f(r)\dot{t}=const\equiv\gamma$ which is the energy of the particle.

Now, for timelike particles, $2\mathcal{L}=-1,$ so $$\dot{r}^2=f(r)+f(r)^2\dot{t}^2=f(r)+\gamma^2\geq0.$$

The inequality is simply there because $\dot{r}^2\geq0.$ We can now think of $f(r)$ as an effective potential, and plot $\gamma^2$ vs. $r$, where $\dot{r}=0$ are the turning points of the radial trajectories (thick curve in the figure).

[image]

$\dot{r}=0,$ is equivalent to $\gamma^2=-f(r)=1-\frac{2M}{r}.$ At $r=2M, \gamma^2=0$ and as $r\rightarrow \infty, \gamma^2\rightarrow 1.$

The point is, if $\dot{r}$ is monotonic as argued by Javier, a particle with initial condition $\dot{r}<0$ (i.e. moving towards smaller $r$), the particle will inevitably move towards $r=0.$